# Why is the size of fonts from production css different from development when using same css in browser?

Tags: django, lighttpd

I corrected my setup.py to have my lighttpd server serve the static files for production.  The pages in production correctly call the css, but my problem is that the sizes are really different from the pages in development despite them having the same css file.

When I look at the source code from the browser, the same thing happens.  The css source for production in the browser window looks smaller than the css source for development.  What can possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Viewing source doesn't apply CSS.

Reset browser zoom? Push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (for most browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are not using "pt" (point) units to declare your font size.  Many factors across different browsers will make this behave differently.  Instead, always list font sizes in "px" (pixel) units.